# Lenovo G50-80 suspend freeze on Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, 16.04, lenovo, fan

I have recently installed Kubuntu 16.04 LTS alongside Windows 10 Pro on one HDD. System selection works. But when I use suspend in Kubuntu computer freezes entirely. Screen turn off, but all LEDs are still lit (power indicators, and CapsLk and NumLock stays lit if they were lit prior to suspend and cannot be switched off). And lastly the fan is going crazy speeding up to full speed after a short time. It does it by steps, like if the cpu was heating up, but air blowing from it is colder than in normal use of the laptop. And anything I could do is holding power button to power off the lapton. In Windows 10 suspend works with no problem.

I have edited question in accordance to Steve Roome comment:

> Try the steps in the answer to "How can I figure out why Suspend sometimes fails?" and edit your question to include the output. You can use paste.ubuntu.com

This is fragment of syslog.log starting with Starting suspend
http://paste.ubuntu.com/16282143/

The `dmesg -T|grep Freez -A4` does not show anything so I am adding full `dmesg` output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/16282528/

I also recently noticed that hdd is stoping when I try to susppend pc.

Comment: And here is output of `dmesg -T|grep Failed` http://paste.ubuntu.com/16282628/ (It seems there is a problem with ACPI, if I am not mistaken). I also found lines with ACPI Error: http://paste.ubuntu.com/16282810/

Comment: In windows 8.1 and 7 there was problem with Lenovo ACPI driver, it was to be installed manually , I does not know if it has any relevance to this matter (and It does not), but without this driver and control program there was issues with battery life and power savin features in windows.

Comment: is it this bug? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1559805

Comment: It seems so. How can I get suspend log? I does not see it in folder where other logs are located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to other distribution (Kubunto to Ubuntu Mate) does not fix this problem. However installing kernel 4.4.8 seems to fix this issue (tested few times in Mate). I does not know if it is persistent, or I have luck five times in a row. I does not tested it in kubuntu, but result should be same. Suspend however takes much more time than in 14.04 (up to 15 seconds in 16.04, almost instant in 14.04). Thanks to all people involved in finding answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try opening your terminal (`Ctrl+Alt+T`), then paste the following: `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and enter your superuser password.

In the opened file, copy and paste (`Ctrl+Shift+V`) the following lines beneath the first comment, for simplicity:

```
blacklist dw_dmac
blacklist dw_dmac_core
```

Then save this file again (`Ctrl+Shift+O`) and close it (`Ctrl+Shift+X`).

Suspend should work now without freezing. If you have shutdown/boot issues, try blacklisting these modules in grub as well. If you have a terminal open, enter: `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and change the line

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

to

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash
>   modprobe.blacklist=dw_dmac,dw_dmac_core"

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. I have no problems with shutdown or boot, only with suspend. And this solution is not working at all.
The file should look like these?

`# This file lists those modules which we don't want to be loaded by`
`# alias expansion, usually so some other driver will be loaded for the`
`# device instead.`
`blacklist dw_dmac`
`blacklist dw_dmac_core`

Comment: Judging by the bare text it looks correct, unfortunately I can't see the line breaks in your comment. Make sure that both the "blacklist ..." parameters are on their own lines *beneath* the comments (without a # anywhere before them). When in doubt, just move the file contents down and add them right at the top on the first two lines of the file. If that still does not work for you, then your problem must slightly differ from what I have experienced, but the symptoms you described sound exactly like a dw_dmac module issue.

Comment: They are in seperate lines. And are not commented.

Comment: Okay, if this is the case and it still does not work, then I can't help you, sorry. You may then delete those entries again. Have you tried this on the regular Ubuntu? I have never used Kubuntu personally, but like I said, the symptoms sound familiar.

Comment: Try the steps in the answer to "How can I figure out why Suspend sometimes fails?" and edit your question to include the output. You can use paste.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my Lenovo. I upgraded my bios and now everything works fine. You have to execute the upgrade program in Windows and then it will restart your computer and updates the bios fully automaticly

Comment: I do this some time ago, and there is no newer bios version available. I have currently installed B0CN97WW version of bios, which is stated to be updated at 2016/01/08. I does not see newer version on lenovo support page. Have you changed your bios settings somehow or you using default settings?

Comment: @JędrzejPapiernik my pc operates strange, when I reset bios, Windows works, but not Linux. After upgrading bios windows was throughing Bluescreens, but Linux worked perfectly. So no dual boot for me

Comment: For me after bios update pc was booting straight to windows, but switching from legacy to UEFI fixed this. I have no problems with windows (I typing this from it now), only problem I have is suspend on kubuntu. I have same problem on my desktop pc which was runnig Ubuntu 14.04LTS, but I read it was happening because of problems with Gigbyte motherboards (and it was one of many problems with it).

Comment: It is possible that you problem with blue screens in Windows is caused by SATA settings in bios, on windows 7 and 8.1 when I changed them from legacy to AHCI mode windows start showing bluescreen while after load screen was showing.

Comment: That might be possible. There is a os option, where I can switch between off and Windows 8. Apart from that dual boot is not necessary for me. The laptop has less power to play games

Comment: Guys, you're throwing around a lot of different terms here. First of all "Legacy boot" simply means using the older BIOS interface of the mainboard for boot instead of the new UEFI, which has additional functionality, such as "Secure Boot", making sure that only systems with a certain signature can be booted (in your case *probably* Windows 8). With Ubuntu, you can not simply switch between UEFI and Legacy boot, as their bootloaders differ. Lastly, AHCI (not to be confused with ACPI power management) is enabling faster ATA drive speeds and should be selected unless you're using old IDE drives.